# Custom Post Type to override theme's CSS & HTML from Plugins Dir?

Tags: plugin-development

I have a plugin that creates a custom post type called Squeeze Pages. It has various short codes users can enter to make a squeeze page but I'm not sure how I can go about making the squeeze pages have a custom design, completely different from the homepage.

Is this possible? If so, how can it be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below retrieves the custom post type of the currently displayed content and then decides wheter to print on of your stylesheets. Everything happens depending on your page name. You could also `var_dump($ctp_obj_name);` or `printr($ctp_obj_name);` and look what else the custom post type object has to offer and decide what you'll use instead of the name.

The following should reside in your functions.php or in some file included from there:

```
add_action( 'init', 'print_squeeze_style' );
function print_squeeze_style() {
    define( 'YOUR_PATH', get_bloginfo('stylesheetpath').'/squeeze_css_dir/' ); // define css folder for squeeze here
    $post_type = 'your_custom_post_type'; // define custom post type name here

    // ID of post type currently displayed 
    $ctp_ID = get_the_ID();
        // retrieve the whole ctp object of the current "post"
        $ctp_obj = get_post_type( $ctp_ID );
            $ctp_obj_name = $ctp_obj->name; // get name
            $ctp_obj_type = $post->post_type; // type

    // file name depending on Custom Post Type Page Name
    if ( $ctp_obj_name == 'page name A' ) {
        $file = 'filename_a.css';
    }
    elseif ( $ctp_obj_name == 'page name B' ) {
        $file = 'filename_b.css';
    }
    else {
        $file = 'filename_default.css';
    }

    // Register the stylesheet for printing
    if ( post_type_exists( $post_type ) )
        wp_register_style( 'squeeze-css', YOUR_PATH.$file, false, '0.0', 'screen' );


    // print styles depending on Custom Post Type Page Name
    // Then output/print style in head
    if ( $ctp_obj_type == $post_type ) {
        add_action( 'wp_head', wp_print_styles( 'squeeze-css' ) );
    }
}
```

As stated below (please upvote previous Answers too), you'll need an filter on the body_class() function output to do stuff like `body.squeeze div.wrapper div.post .some_element_class`

```
add_filter( 'body_class', 'body_class_for_squeeze' );
function body_class_for_squeeze( $classes ) {
    $post_type = 'your_custom_post_type'; // define custom post type name here
    // ID of post type currently displayed 
    $ctp_ID = get_the_ID();
    // retrieve the whole ctp object of the current "post"
    $ctp_obj = get_post_type( $ctp_ID );
        $ctp_obj_name = $ctp_obj->name; // get name
        $ctp_obj_type = $post->post_type; // type

        // abort if we're not on a squeeze page
        if ( $ctp_obj_type !== $post_type )
            return;
            $classes[] .= 'squeeze';

    return $classes;
}
```

Comment: Just from having a brief look at my code: $ctp_obj_type = $post->post_type; should be $ctp_obj_type = $ctp_obj->post_type; both in the function and in the filter callback fn.

Answer (score 1):

It is easier to do in theme, with native `single-{post_type}.php` [template in hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy#Single_Post_display).

With plugin this is more tricky. My idea would be to to try filter `single_template` hook in [`get_single_template()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_single_template) with path to template file in your plugin's folder (don't forget to check for your post type).

Comment: Or if not the single template(ie. if the plugin is used in pages), then use this approach but tack onto `page_template` instead. Same solution, different hook(just to clarify Rarst's answer is usable in both cases).

Comment: @t31os I am not entirely sure, but I think CPT are in `is_single()`, not `is_page()` templates branch?

Comment: I simply was saying that if the list of custom posts is being displayed on a page, this solution would still be workable, just using an alternative hook. ;)

Comment: @t31os ah... yeah, until we get CPT archives in 3.1 **\*headdesk\***

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to create a secondary CSS sheet for the squeeze page. Then, include a function that adds a new body class and build your CSS off that.